# How to generate GPS / GNSS input stream for RTKLib as a Rover simulation?

Tags: gps, real-time-kinematic

I'm using `RTKNAVI` in `RTKLib`. The `RTKLib` provides example data in a recorded file, in NovAtel OEM6 format, for Rover input stream. The supported data format now is from common format or property brands: RTCM2/3, NovAtel, u-blox,  Skytraq, BINEX etc... and the connection may be static file, or Serial port or TCP/IP port.

I want to provide my own data for testing, but I don't have access to any hardware at this time, also my location is fixed and it should not moving around when programming. So I want to use some simulated data from any available GPS generator, ideal from any free, downloadable source.

However I cannot find any such software or tool doing that. There are some GPS / GNSS  generator and saved in some plain format, but as I know, the format must be in raw data for processing with the NTRIP RTCM correction.

Some candidates:

https://github.com/mayeranalytics/pyUBX : The u-blox UBX protocol parse / generate, but not simulation for moving?

https://www.nmeagen.org/ : Can generate moving and save the points to NMEA file, but I don't think the RTKLib can read that NMEA format and the data is enough for input stream?

Please tell me any solution if any.